# Not able to access attributes in xml

Tags: php, simplexml

Am trying to access the attribute of the simple xml

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Index] => 21
        )

    [Data] => Hello world
)
```

i want to access Index attribute. I tried the following code but its not
working for me

```
$xml->attributes()->Index
```

Comment: add `echo` to it

Comment: try `echo $xml->attributes['Index'];`

Answer (score 0):

There you go my friend:

```
$xml->attributes()['Index']
```

Sometimes I noticed I had to cast the result when it's a string. Like:

```
(string)$xml->attributes()['Index']
```